# Can you take screenshots of XBox 360 games?

Tags: xbox-360

The question's probably enough -- but can you take (in-software/hardware) screen shots of arbitrary XBox 360 games, and if so, how? Also, if you can, how would you get the image off the 360 and onto, say, your computer?

(Currently, I resorted to snapping an actual -- bad -- photograph of my TV screen.)

Answer (score 4):

I use a [slingbox](http://www.slingmedia.com/) and [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) to record game play and take screen shots. It isn't a great solution for everyone (a bit pricey) but it does what I need. I've heard of other people using a [HAVA](http://www.myhava.com/products.html) in conjunction with FRAPS.

Answer (score 2):

I have used a program/hardware called [Pinnacle Dazzle](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/PublicSite/us/Products/Consumer+Products/Dazzle/Dazzle+Video+Archiving/Dazzle+Video+Creator+Plus+HD.htm). It records video and can take screen shots but it costs a good amount of money.

It is a little extreme for just taking pictures because it has video editing software included, but is an option. Its a very nice piece of hardware.

Answer (score 2):

If your TV has a signal output, you could just record it to a DVR or something and come back later for the screenshots.  I use an rewritable so that I don't waste dvds.  Simplest solution to implement since I have a DVR

Answer (score -1):

I know you are looking for arbitrary games, but some games such as Halo or Skate allow users to take screenshots at certain times or for certain features of the game.