# Easiest way to screenshot an XBox 360, Playstation 3, or Wii Game?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, nintendo-wii

What's the easiest way to take a screenshot of an XBox 360 or other console game?

Do I really have to buy a video card with HDMI/HDTV support, plug the XBox into that, and do the screen cap on the computer? What about a way to do this within the XBox itself, or by using a 3rd-party piece of "capture" hardware?

How is this typically done?

Comment: Really good question by the way.  I think this is often wondered

Comment: Related: [Can you take screenshots of XBox 360 games?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6941/58)

Answer (score 8):

Well, the most 'professional' way to take a screen capture is to buy a [capture card](http://shop.ebay.com/?_from=R40&_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=hd+capture+card&_sacat=See-All-Categories) or run a video signal into a PC and use video capturing software. (Frapps?)  I have used a 'Dazzle Platinum' myself. (which forced me to play in standard definition and made me give up on my old youtube channel)  That being said, if your looking for a screenshot for bragging rights, (or to make a how-to) I have often seen a digital camera used to take a picture of the screen.  While this is not the ideal solution, if you decrease back light (glare) and turn off your flash its often legible.

These are the only two ways to do it at the moment.  Some games are beginning to support in game 'montage video editing' (black-ops has this option) but until this technology matures your really only left with the two options.  Capture the image through the wire, or capture the image through the display (tv or monitor).

I hope this helps

Comment: Your answer is fine, but is not describing easy ways (easy, in the sense of neither time nor money consuming.)

Answer (score 6):

All I do is take a picture on my cameraphone

Comment: Well, this certainly is the *easiest* way.

Comment: Camera at screen is the easiest way which is exactly what the question asked.

Comment: CRTs were harder to capture because of the glass surface and the refresh rate striping (not visible until you took the shot), but, LCDs, especially the non-glossy ones give pretty good results.

Comment: Only issues I've had with this method is the colors sometimes don't look right, better camera probably fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use a [slingbox](http://www.slingmedia.com/) and [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) to record game play and take screen shots. It isn't a great solution for everyone (a bit pricey) but it does what I need. I've heard of other people using a [HAVA](http://www.myhava.com/products.html) in conjunction with FRAPS. It should support any of the consoles that have composite or component outputs. As a plus it allows you to continue playing in HD, but records in SD.

Answer (score -1):

I use my camera. Just put it somewhere it can be still and wait for it to focus a little. Then when I see that its focused I take the picture or take the video.

Comment: This doesn't add any new information.